# How to implement background task for react-native IOS

Tags: ios, react-native

We are using Geolocation.watchPosition in our app, This service working for the foreground but its not working in the background **(For IOS only)**

We try background timer but it also stops after some time(5 minutes).
[react-native-background-timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-timer)

For Geolocation:: [react-native-geolocation-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geolocation-service)

**Requirement:** We need the services(Geolocation) will work in foreground and background.

**Permissions::**

```
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
```

**React-native code::**

```
this.watchId = Geolocation.watchPosition(async (response) => {
    console.log(response)
}, async (error) => {
    console.log(error);
}, {
    accuracy: {
        android: 'high',
        ios: 'best',
    },
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    distanceFilter: 5,
    showLocationDialog: true,
    fastestInterval: 0,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hidden (yay) but in [`react-native-geolocation-service` setup.md](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service/blob/master/docs/setup.md) says that you have to add location capability in xcode project.

When you call `watchPosition` it will remain in background and will show a notification in Android and a blue pill in iPhone clock if you minimize app.

If you close app in iOS the process will finish. I don't remember what happen in Android with it.

I think it worked well enough with only `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` permission so I left it only with that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Have you added background permissions to your app? Internet, coarse location and fine location permissions?

Comment: Yes, I did all these permission in our app.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: @HarleenKaurArora, I went through the docs and I saw a timeout parameter which is missing in your snippet. Can you try adding that to see if it'll work?
https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.63/geolocation#watchposition